# How to write text into log4net file

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have a C# application. I would like to integrate a log File. Then I try do this in App.config

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="InfoFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="info_logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />

    </appender>
    <appender name="ErrorFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="error_logfile.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
      <level value="DEBUG" />
      <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
      <level value="INFO" />
      <appender-ref ref="InfoFileAppender" />
      <level value="ERROR" />
      <appender-ref ref="ErrorFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

So I try to write in infoFile:

```
log.Info("chiamata json");
```

but I don't see any text in info_logfile.txt

Where is my error?

Can we help me?

Reguards

Answer (score 0):

Do you instantiate your log file? Try the following to see that it works with a console appender. (this example is copied from David Saltner)

```
using log4net;
using log4net.Config;

public class LogTest
{
    private static readonly ILog logger = 
           LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogTest));

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();

        logger.Debug("Here is a debug log.");
        logger.Info("... and an Info log.");
        logger.Warn("... and a warning.");
        logger.Error("... and an error.");
        logger.Fatal("... and a fatal error.");
    }
}
```

.

```
private static readonly ILog logger = 
          LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(LogTest));
```

This creates a logger for the class LogTest. You don't have to use a different logger for each class you have, you can use different loggers for different sections or packages within your code. The class of the logger is output to the log so you know where any logged information has come from.

`BasicConfigurator.Configure();`

This method initializes the log4net system to use a simple Console appender. Using this allows us to quickly see how log4net works without having to set up different appenders.

This should get you started. Check out this [great article for a brief introduction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8245/A-Brief-Introduction-to-the-log-net-logging-librar) on how to set up appenders and more.

Answer (score 0):

If the configuration is in your app.config file you need to add the sections in the config file:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="log4net" 
   type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, 
         Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" />
</configSections>
```

It is better practice to configure your log4.net is a log4net.config file. Then you need to add the following line to your assembly which reads your configuration file:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```